# Ext.toolbar.Toolbar with overflowHandler scroll to end

Tags: javascript, extjs, toolbar

Is there any property/config to say that the toolbar, when its overflowting to the right should scroll to the last item? I have a vertical toolbar. And it should scroll to the last item on the right

My config looks like:

```
var toolbar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
    cls: 'toolbar',
    dock: toolbarDock,
    border: false,
    overflowHandler: 'scroller',
    items: [this.toolbar]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add parameter like `enableOverflow` as `true` to use `overflowHandler`.

[Check sencha documentation `enableOverflow`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar.html#cfg-enableOverflow)